# How to make 3.2 APDI slider emulator

Tags: android, emulation

Hey i am making a app in which i want to make emulator that should be 320 X 480 i.e. APDI emulator .Can anyone help me out ...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HvGA is the emulator whose ewsolution is 320X480

Answer (score 1):

The HVGA emulator is 320 X 480 only

Answer (score 0):

HVGA emulator is one You are looking for ..